# Salesforce Lightning Super Badge - 8

Tags: lightning, trailhead, superbadges

I have problem to pass 8 step in salesforce lightning superbadge. 
I don't know why... I using new playground.

I prepare 3 files from excel file from 3 tabs:

1. Explorers - I split full name to first name and last name
2. Adventures - I added standart pricebookid,
3. OppInfo - i added 3 fields for - opportunity, contact, pricebookid

What I did:

1. load Explorers,
2. load Adventures
3. load pricebook
4. load opportunity
5. load opportunity contact role - I think i have problem with it
6. I try load Adventure packages and I have below problem:

[image]

Comment: You might check the [Trailhead community group](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F9300000009Nek) to see if anyone else has run into this.

Answer (score 2):

Going on the error message alone:

> Price Book Entry ID: id value of incorrect type: 01s.....

Something is looking for a PricebookEntry ID ([01u keyprefix](http://www.fishofprey.com/2011/09/obscure-salesforce-object-key-prefixes.html#01u)) and is instead getting a Pricebook2 Id ([01s keyprefix](http://www.fishofprey.com/2011/09/obscure-salesforce-object-key-prefixes.html#01s))

Check the ID's you are putting in for the Price Book Entry ID are infact IDs for the correct record types.

See also:

- [Product and Schedule Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_products.htm) Data Model

Comment: hm, thank you - I loaded all of data but I can't pass ... you pass this chalang? 
could you provide scrren with opportunity/opplineitem/products/price book. 
Or check in my environment where I have problem?
I don't know what i doing wrong.